# what is the meaning of Samples in Performance Profiler?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

Currently I am working on the Performance of a tool and there was Inclusive and Exclusive Samples mentioned in the Microsoft Visual Studio Performance Profiler results.

Also, is there any way where I can convert it into milliseconds.

I am very new to this, and it would be great if anyone could help me understand this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read about it here

[What are Exclusive and Inclusive?!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/profiler/2004/06/09/what-are-exclusive-and-inclusive/)

> - Exclusive time is the amount of execution time that passed while within that function excluding the time spent in functions called from
>     that function.
> - Inclusive time is the amount of execution time that passed while within that function including the time spent in function called from
>     that function.

As for milliseconds

[How to see milliseconds in Visual Studio Performance Analyzer instead of % samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362448/how-to-see-milliseconds-in-visual-studio-performance-analyzer-instead-of-sampl)

> The sampling profiling method interrupts the computer processor at set
>   intervals and collects the function call stack. Exclusive sample
>   counts are incremented for the function that is executing and
>   inclusive counts are incremented for all of the calling functions on
>   the call stack. Sampling reports present the totals of these counts
>   for the profiled module, function, source code line, and instruction.

Comment: I read it, Thanks, I also wanted to know why it is called Samples ?